# regex - can contain slash, just not at the start or end

Tags: regex

I am white-belt regex.

I have the following regex which sort of works except allowing
/

Below "the below regex" I have listed my rules. also, i think my regex needs to be reversed because i want the match count to be greater than zero when invalid data is entered.

Here is my regex so far which i think is still way off the mark:

```
^[/]|[=`~!@#$%^&*(){}\[\]:;"'<,>\.?]|//
```

I wish the following cases to return a match count

```
/  
hello  
hello/world  
hello/to/my/world
```

i wish the following cases to return a match count of zero.

```
(blank_not_allowed)  
/hello  
hello/  
/hello/
hello.aspx  
hello/world.aspx  
hello//world
hello?
```

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? A regex might not be the best solution...

Comment: im trying to restrict entry into a field of incorrect data and only want to allow the cases listed under "I wish the following cases to return a match count of zero". The system I am working with only accepts the data if there are not data entry errors.

Comment: Also, I agree with @Byron.  What you are trying to do here seems odd to me...

Comment: @Abe Miessler: /hello/ should not be allowed, thanks

Comment: so from what I understand all these at the bottom are errors and only the ones provided in the first block are the ones you want to pass?

Comment: Why did you move my edit?  Are you saying that if it returns a match count it's not allowed?

Comment: @tom tu: that is correct, thanks

Comment: @abe Miessler: that is correct, a match count = 0 is an error.

Comment: If it returns a match count then match count is NOT equal to zero... Right?

Comment: Your comments contradict themselves.  You need to clarify the following: 1) Does match count = 0 signify an errror.  2) Should `/hello/` be allowed?

Comment: @abe, sorry for confusion. 1) yes, match count of zero = error. 2) /hello/ should result in zero match count and therefore an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work, although (phrase)+ isn't something I've tested (and would be happy to hear feedback on):

> /^((\/)|([a-z]+\/{0,1}[a-z]+)+)$/

I may have gotten carried away with the brackets...

Comment: I tested the regex. It fails if there is one character. For example "a". That string should match.