# Generic validate input data via regex. Input error when match.count == 0

Tags: .net, regex, validation

I have a number of types of data fields on an input form, for example, a web page.

Some fields are like, must be an email address, must be a number, must be a number between, must have certain characters. Basically, the list is undefinable.

I wish to come up with a generic way of validating the data inputed. I thought I would use regex to validate the data. The fields which need validation would be related to a "regex expression" and a "regex error message" stating what the field should contain.

My current mock up has that when the match count is zero, that would signify an error and to display the message. While still a white belt regex designer I have come to understand that in certain situations that it is difficult to write a regex which results in a match count of zero for every case.

A complex regex case I looked for help on was [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893101/regex-can-contain-slash-just-not-at-the-start-or-end). The forum post was a disaster because I confused people helping me. But one of the statements said that it was difficult to make a regex with a match count of zero meaning the input data was invalid; that the regex was very difficult to write that for.

Does anyone have comments or suggestions on this generic validation system I am trying to create?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`My current mock up has that when the match count is zero, that would signify an error and to display the message.`

In this case you have to have multiple regex's and each one must be used on and pass each input box.

Pseudo code:

```
Array of regex's:  
[0] = /something[class] something else/
[1] = /more stiff that must be in each one/

result = 1;
loop through array
    if ((result = result && match_globally(regex[i])) == 0)
        break;
end loop

if (result == 0)
    notify of an input error at regex[i] validation
```

Comment: are you saying that for a single field, I should have multiple regex expressions. And if they do not all pass for that field, then show the error message?

Comment: Yea, essentially you are trying to ammas invalidity into a single regex. Thats impossible. Create general regex's of forms that are valid, if one fails it's invalid. So they must all have a commonality relative to the form data. This is just my opinion.